# jquery 101 form submit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Surprisingly I am missing something in my jquery 101 code. FOllowing is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
      event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="target" action="#">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and corresponding plnkr link is

http://plnkr.co/edit/lib2XGtHwJYVfiFKcK8n?p=preview

Comment: ?what you mean by not working

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6xmZMByR7EY8VNtVpsdL?p=preview

Comment: Read the jQuery docs for the DOM ready event handler:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your page loads, your script (which is at the top of your page) runs immediately, before the `#target` element exists.  Therefore your `.submit` does not get bound.

There's a couple options for correcting this.

The most common (and best practice, really) is to wrap the function in a [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function:

```
<script>
    // This is the shorthand version of document ready
    jQuery(function($) {
        $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
            alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
            event.preventDefault();
        });
     });
</script>
```

Or, you can use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), which binds to any element, even those created after the script is run.  This is particularly useful when you create elements dynamically, as it will bind to those elements also:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('submit', "#target", function( event ) {
      alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
      event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

[Demo of event delegation](http://plnkr.co/edit/nc5UMfRdgIolOauHn77a?p=preview)

Comment: +1 for not just dumping code without an explanation.

Comment: @Sparky - thanks.  I figure they don't understand, so it's best to help them understand why, and walk them through different options when possible.

Answer (score 1):

**JQuery**

```
 $(function () {
        $("#target").on("submit",null,function( event ) {
          alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
          event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why? What does this do? How does it work? (I know, but you should explain for the OP).  You should point out that this is the shorthand document ready function, also.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This is going to allow your jquery to wait for the document to be ready before it is allowed to run (thank you Caleb)

Comment: Why? What does this do? How does it work? (I know, but you should explain for the OP).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
      event.preventDefault();
    });
)};
</script>
```

They must be declared ready or load function because the jquery compiler will execute function when the document loaded and event.prevenDefault function is prevent form the default action but the above code has no action. preventDefalut option example refers from jqueryApI.